# Return value from function "outside"

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner in Laravel and php.

I have this code:

```
$arrayToDelete = array();
$traverse = function ($categories) use (&$traverse) {
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        //$this->model->delete($category->id);
        echo 'Delete'.$category->category_name.' i '.$category->id.'<br/>';
        $traverse($category->children);
    }
};

dd($traverse($node));
```

This code return me:

> Delete Mobile i 14 Delete Samsung i 15 Delete iPhone i 16 Delete Xiomi
>   i 17

It's ok.
I need add id to $arrayToDelete. How can I make it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass more than one parameter into the USE so pass your other array, also by reference of course

```
$arrayToDelete = array();
$traverse = function ($categories) use(&$traverse, &$arrayToDelete) {
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        arrayToDelete[] = $category->id;
        echo 'Delete'.$category->category_name.' i '.$category->id.'<br/>';
        $traverse($category->children);
    }
};

dd($traverse($node));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$arrayToDelete = [];
$traverse = function ($categories) use (&$traverse,&$arrayToDelete) {
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        //$this->model->delete($category->id);
        echo 'Delete'.$category->category_name.' i '.$category->id.'<br/>';

        $arrayToDelete[] = $category->id;

        $traverse($category->children);
    }
};

dd($traverse($node));
```

Comment: I make this: $arrayToDelete = [];
        $traverse = function ($categories) use (&$traverse) {
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                //$this->model->delete($category->id);
                echo 'Delete'.$category->category_name.' i '.$category->id.'<br/>';

                $arrayToDelete[] = $category->id;

                $traverse($category->children);
            }
        };
        $traverse($node);
        dd($arrayToDelete); and this is not working :(

Comment: Please don't write any long code as comment, this is not readable. Please update your question

Comment: Please use $arrayToDelete in use

Comment: It's not working :(

Comment: Sorry my mistake, please use $arrayToDelete in use with &

Comment: Is it working now?